# How to change dns setting using powershell

Tags: powershell

I am really confused where to start from I would like to populate just two fields in network adapter setting. those two fields are preferred DNS and alternate DNS. The ip will be allocated dynamically using DHCP. At the moment I fill the two fields manually but i want a powershell script to do this. I searched over internet but its really confusing. Can some one please help

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure if Powershell itself has such function but you could use [netsh](http://msdn.microsoft.com/http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc738592(v=ws.10).aspx/library/cc738592(v=ws.10).aspx) from Powershell like this:

```
netsh interface ip set dns "<connection name>" static 1.2.3.4 primary
netsh interface ip add dns "<connection name>" 1.2.3.5
```

You may also use WMI to adjust LAN interface settings but I think this is way easier.

Comment: what would be the <connection name> i assume its default Local Area connection???

Comment: Yep, in Windows you have a name for every connection. I don't know the default name in englisch, for me in my german Windows it's called "LAN-Verbindung"

Comment: i used the above two lines while replacing the connection name and correct preferred dns but i am getting error on the second line it says incorrect parameter. with first line i am able to populate the preferred dns field

Answer (score 2):

you could try with wmi :

```
$card=Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_NetworkAdapterConfiguration -Filter "IPEnabled=true" 
$card.EnableStatic('192.168.1.2','255.255.255.0')
$carte.SetGateways('192.168.1.1')
$carte.SetDNSServerSearchOrder(@('192.168.1.10','10.10.1.8'))
```

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at
http://blogs.technet.com/b/danstolts/archive/2012/01/31/using-powershell-to-get-or-set-networkadapterconfiguration-view-and-change-network-settings-including-dhcp-dns-ip-address-and-more-dynamic-and-static-step-by-step.aspx

he shows how to create scripts for static and dynamic, shouldn't be too dificult to adapt to your needs.

Comment: can some one please help me out as to why i m unable to fill the alternate dns field using the above two  lines from @Micheal